# Determine whether set is subset of any member in set of sets

Tags: algorithm, performance

I have a set `A` comprised of sets, and need to determine whether each set in A equals or is a subset of any other set in `A`.

My instinct is to proceed as follows: Take each set `i` in `A`, sort then join its values with some reserved character, and determine whether that composite key exists in a hashmap. If not, add the composite key to the hashmap. Then for each combination of members in `i`, also sort and join those values into a composite key and insert the key into the hashmap. Then proceed to the next set in `A`.

The trouble with this approach is the space requirements are huge, as I have ~.25 million sets in `A` and some have many members. I wanted to accomplish the above in main memory but can't in 16GB of RAM.

Is there a way to approach this task that's more space efficient? I'd be very grateful for any insight others can offer on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how many distinct elements you have, an [inverted index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) might make sense.

The basic idea is that for each element `e` you build a list of set IDs of sets that contain `e`. Then for each set i you intersect the lists (this can be optimized e.g., by sorting the set Ids) of all elements in i to get all sets where all elements of i are contained.

**Example:**

```
set 1: A, C
set 2: B, C, E
set 3: A, C, E
```

Inverted Index:

```
A -> 1, 3
B -> 2
C -> 1, 2, 3
E -> 2, 3
```

Then for set 1 you query the inverted index for `A & C` and intersect the lists which yields `1 and 3` after removing set 1 (as a self-hit) you end up with set 3 which contains set 1. Proceed with the other sets.

Libraries like [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) or [Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/inverted-index.html) support this idea efficiently. There might also be in-memory inverted indices that can do this in RAM.

Comment: thanks very much for this idea -- I'll try to tackle it in RAM and will follow up...